# How to read sqlite text column using jdbc prepared statement in java?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Here is my sqlite table

```
CREATE TABLE hello ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  
    import_data text,  
    export_data text
);
```

Here is my java code

```
Connection sqliteConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = sqliteConnection.prepareStatement("select * from hello where export_data = ?;");
preparedStatement.setString(1, "ABD19E3C63"); // hex string
  ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
  resultSet.next();
  importData  = resultSet.getString("import_data");
  System.out.println(importData); // prints nothing although I checked in the sqlite database that it exists.
```

so importData prints nothing although I can see in the sqlite database that it exists. not sure why?

**sqlite query**

```
select hex(import_data) from hello where hex(export_data)="ABD19E3C63"; // This works
```

**The above query works in sqlite although I declared both columns as text**

Comment: Did you try running this exact query directly from SQLite?

Comment: yes. I just added that to my question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your data set, but if the query won't work in SQLIite then it probably won't work in Java calling SQLite.

Comment: It works in sqlite perhaps you didn't read the comment.

Comment: I can see your query statement in sqlite is not the same as your statement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Should you try this?

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = sqliteConnection.prepareStatement("select * from hello where hex(export_data) = ?;");
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use **looping** statement like the following.

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    String import_data= resultSet.getString("import_data");
     System.out.println("Import_data"+import_data);
}
```

Comment: I just only want to get the first row

Comment: Just use resultSet.first()

Comment: that returns a boolean

Comment: Ok, Add this code preparedStatement.setMaxRows(1);  before executing your query.